What do I enter in the DNS/Proxy fields when connecting an Epson printer to a Macbook?
I am trying to connect my Epson L3250 printer to my Macbook for printing. I downloaded Epson Connect Printer Setup for Mac OS X and started the setup procedure, but I get stuck on the "DNS/Proxy Settings" step. Epson's docs skip over this step.
I've tried two things so far:

If I click "Acquire Settings from the Computer", it immediately gives
a dialogue which says "No DNS/Proxy Information set for your computer
or the printer failed to acquire DNS/proxy information".

If I leave "Automatically acquire DNS server address" checked and
click "next", there is a long wait with a progress bar and a message
saying "Sending setting information to the printer...", followed by a
message saying "Setup failed. Failed to access the DNS server."


I haven't tried the following two options:

I can uncheck "Automatically acquire DNS server address" and enter
primary and secondary DNS servers myself. But I am not sure where/how
to find/create these.

I can check "Use proxy server for HTTPS", and enter an address and
port. But I am not sure how to find/create these.


Should I enter DNS or proxy info manually, and if so, how do I go about finding or creating it? Or are there other things I should try?
My Macbook is connected to the printer using Simple AP. Connecting it additionally via cable makes no difference.

I had a similar issue with a Brother printer at my Aunt's house. Eventually I gave up and used the extremely limited control panel  on the printer itself to get the printer an IP address (DHCP was the option). Once the printer was attached to her wifi the iPad found the printer easily. Also unless you are in a business environment you will never have a proxy as home ISPs don't use them.
